# Non-www .htaccess redirect to www giving 500 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the below `htaccess` redirect setup for any requests that come in on non-www urls to redirect to a valid www url, the issue is that the below code keeps throwing a 500 error with the error message below. If I remove the condition and rule then all works grand, am I doing something wrong in the condition and rule!?

The `htaccess` file is in the root of the web directory.

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Error**

```
RewriteBase takes one argument, the base URL of the per-directory context
```

Comment: http  is missing in the target url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Starkeen, the issue was due to a missing `http://` in the rewrite rule.

**Incorrect Rule**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Fixed/Working Rule**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```